# C# for loop in combobox

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox

I trying to display the currency rate on `label1` but I can't figure out what should I type in `label1.Text =` . So can someone guide me along

```
String[] arr = new string[2];

arr[0] = "US"
arr[1] = "SG"

Combobox1.Items.AddRange(arr);
Combobox2.Items.AddRange(arr);
```

In `combobox1` and `combobox2`

```
double[,] value = new double [2,2];

for(int I =0; I<2; I++)
{
   value[0,0] = 1; // basically if I chose Combobox1 US and Combobox2 US the rate is 1;
   value[0,1] = 1.24; // US to SG
   value[1,0] = 0.80; // SG to US
   value[1,1] = 1; // SG to SG

   Label1.Text = 
}
```

Comment: What do you want to show in Label1? Whatever it is it will have the value given the in the 2nd run of the loop (if you really need a loop). You should assign its value after the loop.

Comment: something like "1$=1.24SG" (i don't how to make the sign)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to print out the value (1, 1.24, 0.08, or 1).

What you can do is create a variable and set its value using if statement, then print the value in Label1

```
double labelValue;

if (value[0,0]) labelValue = 1;
else if (value[0,1]) labelValue = 1.24;
else if (value[1,0]) labelValue = 0.80;
else if (value[1,1]) labelValue = 1;

Label1.Text = labelValue;
```

Comment: Can't I use for loop and get the value to label1?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
double[,] value = new double[,] { { 1, 1.24 }, { 0.8, 1 } };
Label1.Text = value[Combobox1.SelectedIndex, Combobox2.SelectedIndex].ToString();
```

Comment: Yup. I trying to print out the value. Thanks guy :)